# How to use Promise.all with mongoose queries as arguments

Tags: mongoose, promise, ecmascript-6

I'd like to 2 of mongoose queries to run as Promise object via `Promise.all()` function.

If 2 of queries are successfully completed, I'd like to return the results and use them in next `then()` function like below.

mongoose query 1:

```
const _getColRank = (colPoint) => {
  return User.$where('this.email !== "admin@admin"').count({ colPoint: { $gt: colPoint } }).exec();
};
```

mongoose query 2:

```
const _getBattleRank = (battlePoint) => {
  return User.$where('this.email !== "admin@admin"').count({ battlePoint: { $gt: battlePoint } }).exec();
};
```

Promise.all():

```
Promise.all([_getColRank(user.colPoint), _getBattleRank(user.battlePoint)])
.then(ranks => {
  User.findByIdAndUpdate(_id, { colRank: ranks[0], battleRank: ranks[1] }, { upsert: true }).exec();
}
```

Unluckily they always return zero. Now I can't find out what the problem is, so need your help. Please teach me.

Comment: Then there is probably no data in your DB that matches the query.

Comment: OMG..u r right. I had to update to 'ranks[0]+1' and 'ranks[1]+1'. Thank u very much!

Comment: FWIW, `User.where({ email : { $ne : 'admin@admin' } })` will be much faster than using `$where()`.

Comment: COOL! thx for good tip!